# Ustream Status code Broken?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, api

here is the code i am using in my website. For some reason i get nothing.

```
<div style="position:absolute; left:0px; top:0px; width:1200px; height:63px; opacity: 0;" ondrag="return false"; ondragstart="return false"; oncontextmenu="return false;"">

    <img src="wpimages/wpa570f7e0.png" width="1200" height="63" border="0" id="statuslive" name="statuslive" title="" alt="" onload="OnLoadPngFix()" >
</div>


<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<style>
    #statuslive {
        display: block;
        position: fixed;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 100001;
        padding: 0;
    }
</style>
<script>
    var query = 'http://api.ustream.tv/json/channel/codtelevision/getValueOf/status?key=my key only';

    function run() {
        $.getJSON(query, function (data) {
            if (data['results'] == 'live') {
                document.getElementById("statuslive").style.opacity = "1";
                alert('Live');
            } else {
                document.getElementById("statuslive").style.opacity = "0";
                alert('Offline');
            }
        });
        clearTimeout(to);
        setTimeout(run, 1000);
    }
    run();
</script>​​​​​
```

the image does not show even if i am live. I have tried using the latest version of jquery, but i still get no image.

this is what i get:

```
{"results":"offline","msg":null,"error":null,"processTime":true,"version":"mashery-r10"}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're actually asking.  Are you getting unexpected data back from the vendor?  Is this something you should check with the vendor?  If the code itself is behaving unexpectedly, indicate where and on what data.

Comment: Sorry, the image does not appear when i am actually live..also, why are people downvoting my question..i am really needing help

Comment: The downvotes are probably due to this same confusion as to what you're asking.  What's the data coming back from the vendor in this case?  You're saying that your image isn't displaying.  But the conditional for that image is depending on data coming back from an external source.  What is that data?  Does `a == "live"`?  If not, what is `a`?  We can't possibly help you if you don't give us more information.

Comment: well, that is all the code i have...

Comment: The code isn't the problem (as far as we know).  The run-time values of the variables are the problem (or at least the first place to look).  I can only ask for those values so many times...

Comment: sorry, i am 16 and learning..i updated my second block code with better code, but it is still not working

Comment: You've also completely changed the logic in the conditional.  Here you're checking a value: `if (data['results'] == 'live')`  *What is that value?*  Clearly that value is _not_ `'live'`, so what is it?  We can't possibly discern the answer to this question from the code alone.  You have to tell us what the runtime values are.

Comment: well, then it will be offline...which makes it...Else..then show alert...look at updated question

Comment: If its `live` does your alert happen (same for if its not live)?  If it does, then have you checked for sure that your `getElement` is actually getting the element...do something like `var a=document.getElementById("statuslive");alert(a);`...people are having difficulty in understanding where the failure is.

Comment: Still nothing...i added that like you said

Comment: You didnt answer my question and what did `alert(a)` produce?

Comment: nothing...it did not even show up.

Comment: DUDE!!! Answer my first question!....actually, dont bother, Im going to bed.

Answer (score 0):

Try executing the `run` function on dom ready.
Instead of the function call

```
run();
```

write this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    run();
});
```

Comment: what do you mean...could you tell me where to put that in my code?